# emmeans post-hoc comparison of model with interaction and control variables

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I am using this mixed model including fixed effects and random intercepts and slopes:

```r
model=lmer(volt ~ (congruency + condition + channel)^2 - 
    congruency:channel + sessorder + (1 + congruency_code* 
    (condition_code + condition_codelevel3) + sessorder_code + 
    sessorder_codelevel3 + channel_code + channel_codelevel3|pp), 
    REML=T, data=data, control=contr1)
```

with all the fixed effects being categorical variables (`congruency`,2levels; `condition`,3levels; `channel`,3levels) and `sessorder` being used as a control variable (3levels).

In a post-hoc test using `emmeans` I would like to investigate the significant relationship between "condition*channel". For this I am using this code:

```r
emms <- emmeans(model, ~ condition|channel)
summary(pairs(emms),by=NULL,adjust="bonferroni")
```

The results in R indicate that:

```r
Results are averaged over the levels of: congruency, sessorder
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: bonferroni method for 9 tests
```

My question is, is it a problem that this is averaged over my significant control variable "sessorder"? Do I have to take this variable into account somehow for the post-hoc test?

Comment: No, but it might be helpful to display graphically the means for condition * channel for each sessorder, so you can visualize what's going on. also perhaps do post hoc comparisons of sessorder means. This question seems more suited to the CrossValidated forum.